# Visual Studio Code command in Windows not working properly

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code

My question is, how can I make the VS Code command line work properly when manually adding it to PATH on Windows?

Inside of Visual Studio Code, I first tried to install it with the tickbox "install to PATH", but when I typed `code` in the command prompt, it said command not recognized. So I manually edited `PATH` and added `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code`.

However, when running commands such as:

```sh
code -v
```

the command prompt doesn't print anything, but launches Visual Studio Code instead.

Comment: If VSCode is starting, you've properly added it to the PATH (otherwise, you'd get an error message about it not being a valid command). So your question is really why VSCode isn't recognizing the command-line options; you should [edit] to ask that instead. The title (and text about the PATH) are irrelevant.

Comment: If cmd is open then your path gets updated, you may need to restart cmd to get the updated variables.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your path environment variable should include `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin` instead of `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code` (notice the added **`\bin`** at the end).

The `bin` sub directory provides the batch file `code.cmd`, that processes the command line before launching `code.exe` from the parent directory. Going through the batch file is required for the command line to work properly.

Comment: Thanks, my path was "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code", it should have been  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin"

Comment: With the most recent updates of VS code, I needed to amend it to:

C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\_\bin