# code . is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I want to open a directory using cmd in visual studio code but its giving me an error in cmd. So, what setting is required for that?

**I have performed below command**

```
D:\RND>code .
```

Comment: which OS? might need to set the PATH

Comment: @d.moncada: windows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio Code command in Windows not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42542754/visual-studio-code-command-in-windows-not-working-properly)

Answer (score 116, accepted):

It needs to be setup so that Code is found in your `PATH`. If you're on a **mac** system, do the following (for windows systems, read below):

1. Launch VS Code
2. Open up command palette (press <kbd>F1</kbd>) and type `shell command` to find `Shell Command: Install 'code' command in PATH command`.
3. Restart terminal

[image: VSCode screen capture]

If you're on Windows, you can also set the PATH manually by adding:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin
```

to your PATH environment variable.

1. Open command prompt
2. Type the command - `setx path "%path%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin"`
3. Restart terminal

**Update**: If you're on Windows 10 and VSCode 1.47.2 and above, the new PATH has to be set to:

```
C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin
```

Comment: @AnkitBhanderi see picture. you can't find that?

Comment: @AnkitBhanderi does it now work, or am I right that you can't find it?

Comment: Had the same issue but in my case, the path variable was updated for local admin bcoz I installed it with local admin.

Comment: On my win 10 I had to edit the Path manually - Select Path under 'System Variables', click on edit, on the new window click new and add new path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code"

Comment: Uninstall and again install visual code.. it will work

Comment: @d.moncada https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50182417/code-command-is-not-working/52501613#52501613 see no solution is working for me

Comment: In my environment the path is **C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code**

Comment: @ilans is correct. In Windows 10 and VSCode 1.47.2 at least, the PATH has to be `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin`.

Comment: In version 1.49.2 the command palette's shortcut is `shift` + `cmd` + `p`

Comment: In my experience, on Windows 10 and Mac OS Big Sur, I have not been able to find the command palette command to add 'code' to the PATH. Instead, I had to manually edit the path. 

NOTE: Once your path is properly edited, you will need to restart any shell instances for the change to take effect therein.

Comment: slightly different here: `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\_\bin` worked for my machine

Comment: In my case I forgot to restart the Git Bash

Comment: thanks for destroying my dev environment entire path variable is lost!! guess I'm not sleeping tonight! DO NOT TRUST THIS!!!!

Comment: Now is worst!, my CMD Does not find anything, neither other path even if they are still on my path environment

Answer (score 24):

**if using Windows:**

1. Press the "Windows"-button
2. Type "Visual Studio Code"
3. Right click on "VS Code" (or "Visual Studio Code")
4. Click on "Open file location"

You will then be directed to a folder, where either the VS Code program is **or** a VS Code shortcut is.

If it is the shortcut, then right click on it and again press "Open file location".
Copy the path:

[image: path picture]

which in my situation will be: "C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code"

And then do as Chawki posted - paste it into your "Environmnet variables" under "Path".

[image: screenshot of environment variable]

This is just to show, that the two above might not be the solution for you (they weren't for me).

Should this still not work for some reason then try restarting the terminal and/or add "/bin" to the path you have added inside your environment variable.

Answer (score 20):

For me it was due to not running cmd as an administrator. (Right click Command Prompt -> Run as Administrator)

Answer (score 13):

If you have the insider's editions of vscode installed, the command will be `code-insiders`.

Comment: this solved it for me on my LInux machine. To prevent me forgetting, I created an alias `alias code="code-insiders"`

Answer (score 11):

O/S windows

Setting the environment variable path to `C:\Users\chawki\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin` solve the issue.

[image: Like this.]

Comment: Everyone, do not do it, it literally removes all the Paths for different softwares when you add this environmental variable, click "Cancel" before proceeding.

Answer (score 4):

**Is your VS Code corrupted?**

This path issue may indicate that VS Code files are corrupted and you may face other issues. Especially, if `code` command was working before.

**No Repair or Reinstall**

According to Microsoft, repair is [unsupported](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/faq#_installation-appears-to-be-corrupt-unsupported).

**Ultimate solution**

1. Uninstall code from control panel.
2. Download and install code using [the latest installer](https://code.visualstudio.com/download).
3. Make sure to checkbox the path checkbox.

[image]

**Note: All users?**

Download the system installer if you want to make code available to all users.

Finally, enjoy!

Answer (score 4):

1.Enter "**View advanced systems settings**" into the box Type here to search

2.Click "**View advanced systems settings**"

3.Click **Environment Variables**

[image]

3.On *System variables* click button **New**
Then enter the variable name and add the following path
**C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin**

[image]

4.Click OK

5.Close All tab VS Code and open again or Restart

Comment: You can also set it to PATH

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you know where is the installation of VS Code, it can be in Program Files (x86) if you installed the 32bits version or Program Files if you installed the 64bits version [VS Code location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeQnR.png) 
Once you know that Run (Win+r) cmd and type: 
`setx path "%path%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code"`

or

```
setx path "%path%;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code"
```

after that, you can type `code .` to open VS Code with the project of the current folder.

Comment: You should probably avoid using `setx path` because it [truncates the number of characters](https://superuser.com/questions/387619/overcoming-the-1024-character-limit-with-setx).

Answer (score 3):

I tried all the solutions but they didn't work. Turns out that Code was not installed on my system.

First go to the directory `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin` and check if there is a folder named `Microsoft VS Code`. If there isn't any, download it from the website link attached below.

https://code.visualstudio.com/download

Answer (score 1):

The best solution was on Mac is to move MSCode to the applications folder, and on Win is to search for the location of MSCode installation ( like: C:\Users{username}\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin ) then you set the Path.

```
setx path "%path%;C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin
```

Answer (score 1):

Notice that if you're using **VS code insider's editions** instead of using the command "**code .**"  the command will be "**code-insiders .**".

That is obvisly after you set your PATH.

Answer (score 1):

**Windows 11**

- Close the Visual Studio Code
- Open the Environment variables (Control Panel > System and Security > System Properties)
- Edit the variable "Path", creating a `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin`
- Ok and ok in options and run VS Code;
- For test write code in cmd, if to open VS Code is working.

Answer (score 1):

Just uninstall and reinstall the vs code it worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Uninstalling vscode and installing it again, worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

First, check if you're on Windows 10 & Set User variables to

```
C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin
```

Give (OK) in environment variables and relaunch any unclosed terminals and type

```
code
```

Check if you have installed the VScode-insiders version

```
C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code Insiders\bin
```

Give (OK) in environment variables and relaunch any unclosed terminals and type

```
code-insiders
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had two installs of VS Code in Windows 10.  One was appended with (user).

I don't know how this happened but uninstalling the older version fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

If adding the bin to the Windows PATH  and reinstalling VScode does not work, try the following method, which worked for me:

- Go to Windows Registry Editor
- Go to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER -> Software -> Windows -> Command Processor`
- Delete the value inside the **AutoRun** key, usually an if

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znail.png)

This method works for any command and does not throw back errors.

Answer (score 0):

At the time of installation, check the **Add to path option**. If it is not opening through the **cmd** using the command **code .**, then restart your system once and retry the **code .** in cmd again. It should work.