# The VSCode `code .` command is not working in the terminal/command prompt in Windows

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code

[image: this is the line i get when i did shell command in VS code]

I get this error:

> `code .`  is not recognised as an external or internal command, operable program or batch file

Morevoer, shell commands are not coming in my compiler VS code neither do  `setx path "%path%;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code"` is working in command prompt .

Comment: Did you just recently install VS Code? If so, did you restart the Command Prompt after installation?

Comment: Did you have a terminal open?

Comment: @vcsjones yes i have recently installed VS code and i have restarted Command prompt  after installation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [code . is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46638944/code-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found it. In the "search" type `environment variables` then click on the "edit system environment variables".

Inside `Environment variables->Path` put `C:\Users\{your_username}\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin`.

Go to the project folder and open the `cmd` with it typing in the location bar and then type `code .`

That will do.

Comment: Make sure that the Environment variables for this path is in the first place. If not move to the top. This worked for me only after moving this path to first place in the order.

Comment: For what it's worth, mine was in C:\\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin, not the AppData folder. And the issue was that VS code updated, and wouldn't open or open with the code . command for a while before and after a reboot, but eventually opened after trying a handful of times for 30 mins.

Answer (score 50):

It looks as if you do not have the `code` program installed. You can open the Command Palette,

- Mac: <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>
- Windows/Linux: <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>

And search "install command", which should return this as one of the options:

- **Shell Command: Install 'code' command in PATH**

Run that, and it should install the `code` command, after which you should be able to use it.

Comment: FYI - Windows doesn't have a command palette option starting with "Shell Command" ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2QW9.png)).  See my answer below for [how to install code to path **on windows**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73137747/1366033)

Answer (score 21):

For **Mac OS**,
You can paste this into your terminal, or in your `.bashrc` file (or whatever shell config file you are using) :

```
export PATH="$PATH:/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin"
```

Comment: in cmd its its showing up -'export' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Worked for me on macOS

Comment: I'm using the Insiders version. This worked for me:
`export PATH="$PATH:/Applications/Visual Studio Code - Insiders.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin"`. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

make sure you run the command in C folder

Then click window key + R and type `rundll32.exe sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables` 
then enter . 
It will open Environment Variables edit Path variable . 
Check whether you have `C:\Users\{pc name}\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin` if not add it and run code -v in C folder cmd

This worked for me !

Answer (score 2):

in windows problem is with insiders version of VSC.
You can use 'code-insiders .' command or make a copy of 'code-insiders.cmd' file as 'code.cmd' inside folder with code-insider (use 'path' command to see where your VSC is installed)

Comment: This works with WSL in Linux shell.  Very helpful thx!  Path to 'code-insiders' is maybe \home\<user>\.vscode-server-insiders\bin\. . .\bin  ('.' directories/files are hidden by default so you can use `ls -ld .*` to view them.

Answer (score 2):

### For Windows OS

For Windows, you'll need to re-install code.  You can [download](https://code.visualstudio.com/Download) the latest version and just install it overtop of your existing install.

During setup, make sure to check the box to `Add to PATH`

[image: Setup - Add to Path]

**See Also**: [The VSCode docs on installing the CLI](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line#_code-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Answer (score 1):

I recently had to modify the path from `/bin` to `/_`

this is what I used after clicking the edit path variables section and it worked.

`C:\Users\{user_name}\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\_`

make sure the path variable refers to the location of the `.exe`

Answer (score 0):

After installation, you need to restart your computer to make the PATH changes effective. Post restart, the command worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

about  linux, if u can't see the **>shell** option with ctrl+shif+p, You could install via

> sudo snap install --classic code

and try again

> code .

Answer (score 0):

Just adding here since the above answers did not work for me. On windows ten when updating the path do not add the /bin. So the added pat should be `C:\Users\{user_name}\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\`

Answer (score 0):

### Adding the `code` executable to your PATH for use in the Git Bash or MSYS2 terminals

If you're trying to run the `code` command in Windows in a Git Bash (from Git for Windows) terminal, or in an MSYS2 terminal, and VSCode is installed, then you may just need to add the `code` executable to your PATH.

Here's how: from my [MSYS2 setup answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77407282/4561887):

> 1. Install VSCode and add the `code` executable into your PATH:
>
>    Install VSCode from here, if you don't already have it: https://code.visualstudio.com/
>
>    The `code` executable is found in the `"$HOME/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin"` dir.
>
>    Add it to your PATH by adding this line to the bottom of your `~/.bashrc` file:
>
>    ```bash
>    DIR="$HOME/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin"
>    if [ -d "$DIR" ] ; then
>        PATH="$DIR:$PATH"
>    fi
>    ```
>
>    Close and re-open all terminals, *or* run `. ~/.profile` [or `~/.bashrc`] in each one to re-source your `~/.profile` and `~/.bashrc` files.
>
>    Now run `code .` in a terminal and it will open up a new instance of VSCode in your current directory. Now we're rockin'.

Answer (score 0):

If adding the bin to the Windows PATH and reinstalling VScode does not work, try the following method which worked for me:

- Go to Windows Registry Editor
- Go to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER -> Software -> Windows -> Command Processor`
- Delete the value inside the **AutoRun** key, usually an if

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znail.png)

This method works for any command that when used does nothing, not even an error.