# fwrite fails to write full (very large) buffer

Tags: c, fwrite

I have a very large 8GB array of `uint64_t` that I need to write to file.  For some reason, `fwrite()` only writes 290MB (exactly 305,131,520 bytes), then simply stops.  My program is using a full core of the CPU (its only job is to write to file at this point), but Task Manager says disk activity is 0.  I have to Ctrl+C to stop it. Here is my code for writing the array to file:

```
void writeToFile(char* fileName, u64* array, size_t arraySize)
{
    FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen(fileName, "wb");

    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Unable to write file");
    }

    fwrite(array, 8, arraySize, fp);

    fclose(fp);
}
```

If I compile in Visual Studio, it works just fine and writes the entire array.  However, I like to write my code in Visual Studio, then use CodeBlocks and gcc to compile (gcc has better optimizations).  When compiling using gcc, it fails to write more than 290MB.  What is the problem here?

Notes: I am compiling on Windows for Windows, and the program is writing to a Gen 4 NVMe SSD, so it should take <10 seconds to write it.  The gcc I use is `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe` that comes with CodeBlocks.

**EDIT**

Okay here is a minimal reproducible program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

#define u64 uint64_t
#define i64 int64_t

int writeToFile(char* fileName, u64* array, size_t arraySize)
{
    FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen(fileName, "wb");

    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Unable to write file");
        return 1;
    }

    fwrite(array, 8, arraySize, fp);

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    i64 numItems = 1111883624;
    
    u64* array = calloc(numItems, 8);

    for(i64 i = 0; i < numItems; i++)
    {
        array[i] = i;
    }

    printf("\nWriting file...\n");

    char* filePath = "C:\\path\\test.bin";

    int x = writeToFile(filePath, array, numItems);

    if(x == 0)
    {
        printf("DONE");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Save failed");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The commandline (according to CodeBlocks) for compiling is

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe -Wall -O2 -fexpensive-optimizations -O3 -m64 -c "C:\path\main.c" -o obj\Release\main.o

x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe  -o bin\Release\test.exe obj\Release\main.o  -s -O3 -m64
```

For fun, I have been testing different values for `numItems`.  As long as `numItems` is less than `536,870,912` (`512 * 1024 * 1024`) exactly, there is no problem.  After that, it writes part of the file, then seems to get stuck in some loop.  So it appears that even though I am using a 64-bit compiler targeting a 64-bit release, it still has a problem if calling `fwrite()` with more than 4GB of data.

I thought that maybe my out-of-date `gcc` (version `8.1.0`, included with CodeBlocks) might be the problem, but I downloaded the most recent version `13.2.0` that comes with msys2.  The problem persists.

**EDIT 2**

I've been testing various values for `numItems`, and here is a csv of the results:

```
numItems,bytes written,bytes expected,distance to uint32.MAX + 1,gets stuck?  
200000000,1600000000,1600000000,2694967296,NO  
400000000,3200000000,3200000000,1094967296,NO  
536870911,4294967288,4294967288,8,NO  
536870912,0,4294967296,0,YES  
536870913,0,4294967304,-8,YES  
536871424,4096,4294971392,-4096,YES  
600000000,505032704,4800000000,-505032704,YES  
1000000000,3705032704,8000000000,-3705032704,YES  
1073741822,4294963200,8589934576,-4294967280,YES  
1073741823,4294963200,8589934584,-4294967288,YES  
1073741824,0,8589934592,-4294967296,YES  
1073742336,4096,8589938688,4294971392,YES  
1111883624,305131520,8895068992,-4600101696,YES
```

Place into a spreadsheet and split to columns by ',' to read it better.  `fwrite()` must be using 32 bits internally for some reason.  536871424 is interesting because it is (512 * 1024 * 1024) + 512, and it is the first value for numItems after (512 * 1024 * 1024) that writes any data to file.  The 4096 bytes it writes happens to be the allocation unit size for the SSD being written to, but I don't know if that's a coincidence or not.  It is similar for 1073742336, which is (1024 * 1024 * 1024) + 512.

Can anyone else reproduce this?

Comment: Is `arraySize` set to 1GB? Do you have the same problem if you break up the writes into smaller chunks in a loop, say only a few MBs at a time? Just because your memory can handle 8GB at a time doesn't mean the filesystem I/O can.

Comment: Can you write logging statements for `arraySize`, and compare them on the different compiled outputs?

Comment: what is the return value of `fwrite()`?

Comment: The `arraySize` is the ~1 billion elements of the array (each 8 bytes).  It's looking like I will have to write in a loop, but I haven't tried that yet.  It works without needing that when compiled by Visual Studio, but not gcc, and I don't know why.  There is no return value for `fwrite()` because it simply never completes.

Comment: You should _always_ check the return from `fread`/`fwrite` . If you write in chunks of `BUFSIZ` and sum up what `fwrite` returns, you should be fine.

Comment: A debugger should be able to tell you where it is stuck.  What is the underlying libc for this?  `gcc` does not compile directly on Windows last I checked.

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: What is the exact environment you are compiling in?  (mingw?  cygwin?  etc...)  Are you certain you are compiling this for a 64-bit target?

Comment: @Jason gcc absolutely supports windows targets.   You didn't check very hard, perhaps! =p  (Google "gcc on windows", for example?)

Comment: Code should **not** attempt the `fwrite()` if the `fopen()` failed.  Not seeing the "Unable to write file" is insufficient evidence that the open fully worked.

Comment: @BadZen I think I meant with glibc. Mingw and what not has it's own libc right?

Comment: I've decided to just do `fwrite()` in a loop with 200MB chunks.  This works fine, but I'm not going to post it as an answer because the question is **why can't `fwrite()` write a very large buffer in one go when compiled using `gcc`?**.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem, which includes a function `main` and all `#include` directives, as well as the exact input required to reproduce the problem. Can't you create such an example which algorithmically generates the required amount of data and still reproduces the problem?

Comment: Meanwhile, you have edited your question and have added a complete program which you have labelled as a "minimal reproducibe example". Does this program have the exact same behavior that you previously described in the question? Does it stop writing after exactly 305,131,520 bytes? Did you verify this?

Comment: Is ```x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe``` for compiling 32-bits applications? Perhaps adding ```#define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS  64``` at the top of your code helps.

Comment: Another hint: what is the size of ```size_t``` you passed as the third argument in ```writeToFile``` function?

Comment: Check the return of `calloc`...

Comment: It is for sure the 4GiB limit, just use 0x1FFFFFFF and 0x20000000, respectively, for `numItems`. Trying to `#define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS  64` did not help in my reproduction, though.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel: Yes, the example produces exactly the same results, on two different versions of `gcc`

Comment: @ImanAbdollahzadeh: Yes, that is the 64-bit compiler, using the -m64 flag to produce a 64-bit binary.  `sizeof(size_t)` on my computer is 8.

Comment: Testing results have been added above.

Comment: Not related to your issue, but "Unable to write file" is a useless error message.  But it was written to stdout, so it's not really an error message at all.  Use `fp = fopen(fileName, "wb");  if (fp == NULL) { perror(fileName); return 1;}`  It provides a reason for the failure and writes the message to the proper stream.

Comment: I believe that Mingw-w64 uses the implementation of the functions `fwrite` and `calloc` in the DLL of the Microsoft C runtime library. My guess is that Mingw-w64 uses the DLL of an older version of the Microsoft C runtime library (for example `msvcr90.dll`) whereas Visual Studio is using the DLL of a more recent version of the library (for example `msvcp140.dll`). This would explain the different behavior. You can see which DLLs are loaded in a process by using the tool [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer).

Comment: The following DLLs are loaded: `kernel32.dll`, `KernelBase.dll`, `msvcrt.dll` and `ntdll.dll`

Comment: @MrPuzzler: My guess is that the issue is in the function `fwrite` of `msvcrt.dll`, which is a very old version of the Microsoft C runtime library. When you run your program in Visual Studio, you are probably using a more modern version of the Microsoft C runtime library. In Process Explorer, you should also be able to see which DLL that version of your program is using.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel: You're right; the Visual-Studio-compiled version uses `vcruntime140.dll` and `ucrtbase.dll`.  So is there anything that can be done about this?  Also, please post this as the answer.

Comment: @Jason - MinGW, being a "MINimalistic GNU for Windows", does not link against a libc per default.   The Windows platform DLLs have the equivalent functionality (sometimes with the same function signatures, sometimes not).  However, `gcc` doesn't care about this (sorta kinda handwave here, but yeah, basically).  However, Cygwin and MSYS are both gcc environments that link against GNU libc on Windows.  GNU libc and binutils both support Windows targets explicitly, so nothing stops you from using them with MinGW if you like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem appears to be in the implementation of the function `fwrite` in the Microsoft C runtime library `msvcrt.dll`, which is used by Mingw-w64. It does not seem to be able to handle writes of more than 4 [GiB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte#Multiple-byte_units).

The reason why your program works with Visual Studio is that that version of your program does not use `msvcrt.dll`, but instead uses `ucrtbase.dll`, which is a newer version of the Microsoft C runtime library, which does not seem to have this problem.

I was able to reproduce your problem in Visual Studio by using `LoadLibrary` on `msvcrt.dll`, with the following code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define THE_SIZE 4295000000LL
//#define THE_SIZE 4293000000LL

#define LIBRARY_NAME "msvcrt.dll"
//#define LIBRARY_NAME "ucrtbase.dll"

int main( void )
{
    HMODULE hLibrary;
    FILE * (*my_fopen) ( const char *filename, const char *mode );
    size_t (*my_fwrite)( const void *buffer, size_t item_size, size_t num_items, FILE *fp );
    int    (*my_fclose)( FILE *fp );

    // load the specified version of the Microsoft C runtime library
    hLibrary = LoadLibrary(  LIBRARY_NAME );
    if ( hLibrary == NULL )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Error returning value!n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // get the addresses of the required functions
    my_fopen  = (void*)GetProcAddress( hLibrary, "fopen" );
    my_fwrite = (void*)GetProcAddress( hLibrary, "fwrite" );
    my_fclose = (void*)GetProcAddress( hLibrary, "fclose" );

    // verify that all functions were found
    if ( my_fopen == NULL || my_fwrite == NULL || my_fclose == NULL )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "GetProcAddress error!\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // perform the actual test
    FILE *fp;
    const char *buffer = malloc( THE_SIZE );
    printf( "%p\n", fp = my_fopen ( "test.bin", "wb" ) );
    if ( fp != NULL )
    {
        printf( "%zu\n", my_fwrite( buffer, THE_SIZE, 1, fp ) );
        my_fclose( fp );
    }

    // cleanup
    FreeLibrary( hLibrary );
}
```

When using `LoadLibrary` on `msvcrt.dll` and setting `THE_SIZE` to `4295000000LL` (which is slightly above 4 GiB), then `fwrite` misbehaves the same way as you described in the question. However, when I set it to `4293000000LL` (which is slightly lower than 4 GiB), then it works.

If I use `LoadLibrary` on `ucrtbase.dll` instead of `msvcrt.dll`, then it works in both cases.

I am unaware of any way to make Mingw-w64 use the library `uartbase.dll` instead of `msvcrt.dll`. Therefore, I'm afraid that you would have to edit the source code of Mingw-w64, if you want to change that.

Comment: Using `ucrtbase.dll` works great, thank you.  I'll also have the looped `fwrite()` as a backup.  I'm a C noob, so it's nice to see a very clear example of dynamically loading functions from an external dll.

Comment: Try building with GCC in the `ucrt64` terminal. See [my setup here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77407282/4561887). The `clang64` terminal should work too. Both use the ucrt libraries.

Comment: Once again, see my comment above and Gabriel's here.   Are you sure you are building for a 64-bit target and using the 64-bit libraries?