# where is visual studio code path? for the latest version at 21 june 2022

Tags: windows, flutter, visual-studio, dart, command-line

Please how can I add code path to my windows environmental variables? any last advice before I choose to reinstall it or tip when reinstalling?

I installed VS with default settings and here are the paths to all the 'bin' folders. I have tried all in path and did not work

1. C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Msbuild\Current\Bin
2. C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\DIA SDK\bin

and the exe; C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE

I have tried all the manual options at [code . is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46638944/code-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command) and non worked.

I also cannot find the install code to path option when I launch visual studio.

I am learning flutter and dart

Comment: Do you think if you learning flutter and dart, then the path to vscode will be different if you study C# for example? It always seemed to me that the path is always the same. Don't you think so?

Comment: from the link I referenced to from the other solutions you should observe that my own default path is different. I am asking because I have tried to add mine to environmental variables and it still does not add 'code' to cmd

Comment: I have solved it. I was using visual studio from visualstudio.microsoft.com instead of code.visualstudio.com

Answer (score 0):

The defaut path for `code.exe` is
`C:\Users\{user-name}\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\code.exe`

If you find my answer helpful, please mark it as Correct. Thank you!

Comment: that is my problem, for reasons I do not know, it does not save there. Instead it is in 1 and 2 in my question

Comment: Okay, I see you have solved your problem.