# Typescript won't run in command prompt

Tags: typescript, environment-variables

I was following a tutorial on typescript today and they were running tsc commands in the builtin terminal of VScode. I tried following along but I would get that the cmdlet 'tsc' is not recognized. I was never able to run any commands on the VScode builtin terminal, but I never bothered to setup. I decided to finally go about it and came across this post

[Setting up code to be found in Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46638944/code-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

prior to this I was able to run the line tsc sandbox.ts in a folder containing sandbox.ts to convert to sandbox.js so the command tsc was working fine. After following the post and running the command:

setx path "C:\Users{username}\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin"

nothing really happened and I still wasnt abe to run any commands through the VScode terminal. However at this point tsc commands also didn't work inside of the Windows command prompt anymore. I reran the npm install and it was not recognizing the tsc command. I am still very new to environment variables and such so I do not know what happened. Does anyone have a solution?

[image: Typescript installation]

The OS that I am using is Windows 10.

Comment: 1. reset the terminal, 2. if that doesn't work run `npx tsc -v`

Comment: ok the npx tsc -v works, and all the tsc commands work as long as I have npx before it. Is there a way to configure my terminal to make it such that I can run tsc commands without typing npx?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have your path a little bit messed up.

**If** you can run commands like `node` an `npm` but **not** things that you have installed using `npm install -g` then those things may be installed installed in the wrong place, or maybe you are using aaa different `npm` version (in a different location) than you think.

Everything you install with `npm install -g` is installed in the same plase as the `node` binary and the `npm` executaable.

Example of how it should work like:

- `which npm` - prints `/Users/rsp/opt/node/bin/npm` npm is installed here)
- `which rimraf` returns empty output and an error
- `rimraf` - prints `-bash: rimraf: command not found` so no `rimraf` command in the path
- `npm install -g rimraf` - `[...] added 28 packages in 2s [...]`
- `which rimraf` - now it prints `/Users/rsp/opt/node/bin/rimraf` (note the same place as `npm`)

In your case to diagnose the problem, run the `which` command if it is available (or [one of its alternatives for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304319/is-there-an-equivalent-of-which-on-the-windows-command-line)) using commands like:

- `which node`
- `which npm` (write down the directory where it is, e.g. `/a/b/c` if `which` returned `/a/b/c/npm`)
- `which tsc`
- `npm install -g rimraf` (or any other module that installs executables)
- `which rimraf` (should display the same directory aas for `node` and `npm`)
- `rimraf --help`
- `ls /a/b/c` (directory returned by `which npm`) note: use `dir` if `ls` doesn't work
- see what is installed in this directory (there should be `npm`, `node`, `rimraf`)
- `npm remove -g rimraf`

If there is something strange, like `rimraf` in a different directory than `npm`, etc. then I would suggest a afresh `node` installation and trying everything again (including installing `typescript` package to get the `tsc` command).